# I would like to extract the month and day from a date

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

My code

```
SELECT 
    PARSE_DATE('%Y%m%d', CAST(date AS STRING)) AS date, 
    EXTRACT(DAY from date) AS day_of_month,
    EXTRACT(MONTH from date) AS week_of_year,  
    channelGrouping, deviceCategory, sessions, conversions,
```

I would like to turn the date's in my column which is in the form 20170101 into 2017-01-01.

Then I would like to extract the month and day from this. However I keep getting an error:

> No matching signature for function EXTRACT for argument types: DATE_TIME_PART FROM INT64. Supported signatures: EXTRACT(DATE_TIME_PART FROM DATE); EXTRACT(DATE_TIME_PART FROM TIMESTAMP [AT TIME ZONE STRING]); EXTRACT(DATE_TIME_PART FROM DATETIME); EXTRACT(DATE_TIME_PART FROM TIME) at [1:60]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below few options for BigQuery Standard SQL - to avoid multiple pre-parsing

Option 1

```
SELECT 
  date, 
  EXTRACT(DAY FROM date) AS day_of_month,
  EXTRACT(WEEK FROM date) AS week_of_year,  
  channelGrouping, deviceCategory, sessions, conversions, 
FROM `project.dataset.table`, 
UNNEST([PARSE_DATE('%Y%m%d', CAST(date AS STRING))]) date
```

Option 2

```
SELECT 
  date, 
  EXTRACT(DAY FROM date) AS day_of_month,
  EXTRACT(WEEK FROM date) AS week_of_year,  
  channelGrouping, deviceCategory, sessions, conversions, 
FROM (
  SELECT * REPLACE(PARSE_DATE('%Y%m%d', CAST(date AS STRING)) AS date)  
  FROM `project.dataset.table`
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to re-parse the date for each `extract()`:

```
SELECT PARSE_DATE('%Y%m%d', CAST(date AS STRING)) as date,
       EXTRACT(DAY from PARSE_DATE('%Y%m%d',
       EXTRACT(MONTH from PARSE_DATE('%Y%m%d', CAST(date AS STRING))) as week_of_year,
       channelGrouping, deviceCategory, sessions, conversions,
```

However, if the `date` is already a number in YYYYMMDD format, why not just use arithmetic functions:

```
select mod(date, 100) as day,
       mod(floor(date / 100), 100) as month
```